# Natural Language Programming solutions in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, full-text-search, nlp, artificial-intelligence

Is there any library for natural language processing in C# ? Given a question like 'what is `<xyz>`?' 'when is `<xyz>` expiring?' I would like to extract the attributes which help me search some data source and return meaningful results.

For E.g. 'what' in a question giving me the word 'definition' and 'when' giving me 'timeline'. I can program simply this using a limited database of word which refers to questions and map them to these categories, but will NLP offer better treatment of the problem?

Also, I have various data-sources say one, two ,three and I would need a long list of keywords which help me determine the data-source,

for eg. xyz would map to 'one' and abc to 'two'.

**How can I use natural language processing to understand which word falls under which category? Or is there a better way to do the same? Any application of FullTextSearch here?**

Comment: i would prefer microsoft made solutions over open source for this

Comment: Would you consider a web service for that ? Or you absolutely need local processing ?

Comment: I can consider a web service but I need the processing real time. This would be used in an IM request- almost immediate response situation. Would web service be able to provide such performance ? I am not sure about that. can you suggest how do I go about making my own Natural language processor, since it seems an easier option somehow... ? I am thinking of filtering out stuff like prepositions, common nouns and extracting proper names which would be compared with a list. Is this a sensible way to go about it?

Answer (score 2):

You can try Antelope from Proxem and [SharpNLP](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/) third party libraries made in c# for Natural language processing, unfortunately microsoft made library currently not exist in NLP. but you can check out [semantic search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492075.aspx) with SQL Server might be help in your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/). I used it to extract nouns, verbs etc. from text. But it has other features as well. You can port it to C# with [IKVM](https://cwiki.apache.org/OPENNLP/a-quick-guide-to-using-opennlp-from-net.html).

Also, check out [Mallet](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/) although that one is JAVA based.